# How can I find error before my java code at launch?

Tags: java

My project worked a year before with actual Eclipse and java 1.8.
I loaded my proj. with the newest Eclipse 2021 9R (or 12R does not matter) and set javaSE 16 to jvm to my proj.
I have to remove a call of `javafx.Pair` and after it received this, when try to launch:

(Execution not hit the first breakpoint, the project have not error or warning)

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class DailyTasksApplication.DailyTasksApplication
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    DailyTasksApplication/DailyTasksApplication.readConnectionProperties()LDailyTasksApplication/myRedConnectionProperties; @561: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'DailyTasksApplication/myRedConnectionProperties' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @561
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/util/Vector', 'javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder', 'java/io/File', 'org/w3c/dom/Document', 'org/w3c/dom/NodeList', integer }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: bb00 ea59 b700 ec4b b800 edb6 00f3 4cbb
    0000010: 00f7 59b8 00f9 b700 fc4d 2b2c b600 fe4e
    0000020: 2d12 08b9 0104 0200 3a04 0236 0503 3606
    0000030: a701 7819 0415 06b9 010a 0200 3a07 1907
    0000040: c001 1012 0eb9 0112 0200 03b9 010a 0200
    0000050: b901 1301 003a 0819 07c0 0110 120b b901
    0000060: 1202 0003 b901 0a02 00b9 0113 0100 3a09
    0000070: 1908 1226 b601 189a 00a1 1907 c001 1012
```

...

What is @561?

Comment: By the way, Java 16 is end-of-life; use Java 17, a long-term support (LTS) version. And to use the `Pair` class from JavaFX, include the [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) libraries with your project. Or just define your own pairing class, possible as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

Comment: Pair is not problem, I can ignore it. Java 16 or 17 does not matter, I want to upgrade my project from the old 1.8

Answer (score 1):

You can't debug that kind of low level error. It basically means your old compiled bytecodes (xyzblabla.class files)
are doing weird things that should not happen in the rules of your new dependency/environment settings.

If you used jdk1.8 when writing&compiling that project, you should run it with jre1.8. Likewise if you used version x of library y, you shouldn't run it with version x1 of library y.

Anyways quickest fix is clean all build files and recompile.

Comment: I want to upgrade my project to the (almost) newest JVM (16 or 17).
Clean the project, load maven dependencies, was done before I wrote, but now I deleted 'bin' and 'target' directories and the same result at launch.

Comment: I found the problem: the "return" row was too complex for the JVM.
#####################################################
Before:
  return (selectedItemIndex > -1) ? connections.get(selectedItemIndex) : new myRedConnectionProperties("", "", "", "", "", "", "");
 }
#####################################################
After:
  if(connSelectDlg.getSelectedConnIndex() > -1) {
   selectedConn = connections.get(connSelectDlg.getSelectedConnIndex());
  }
  ...
  
  return selectedConn;

Comment: In my opinion it is a JVM problem.